# How to active OpenGL in a HP DV6700 with Intel Graphics card

Tags: 11.04, intel-graphics

The video card is a Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller with 256MB. The user can not play anything that uses OpenGL since it runs REALLY slow. But on Windows it runs perfect.

Using Ubuntu 11.04 without any effects in Ubuntu Classic (No Effects)

Comment: have you tried the x-swat ppa?

Comment: What does the x-swat ppa offer?

Comment: Updated graphics drivers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of issues with this chipset/GPU. Most of the issues revolve around the driver not upto date. Here is the WIKI with all of the fixes to try. There Are A Crap load of them.

UBUNTU WIKI FOR INTEL DRIVERS AND FREEZES
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Bugs/Lucidi8xxFreezes

Hope this helps you out. You are not the only one with the issues.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to disable "Sync To VBlank" option in ccsm?

for more information you can see my previous post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39857/is-my-graphics-card-supported-by-gnome-3/39977#39977)

Comment: I had to add not using compiz or any other 3d effects.

Comment: "The user can not play anything that uses OpenGL since it runs REALLY slow"

Comment: Correct. Anything that uses opengl runs slow.

Comment: did you mean playing video? or playing games?

Comment: is this happened when you used the earlier version of ubuntu ?

Comment: I already mention the ubuntu version above and anything that uses opengl.

Comment: sorry, i mean ubuntu 10.10 or 10.04

Comment: This is a new user testing ubuntu. His first Ubuntu experience is 11.04